# Building a List dynamically w/ objects

Tags: python-3.x

I'm building a list of the SP 500 components to save it in a pickle.

I get the items from the link in the code, then get the info I want and build an object for every item.

Here's the problem -->
I then want to save each object into a list that I will want to iterate in the future.

The list only stores the last object of the loop, instead of storing each object as it shows up.

It should be fairly easy to do this but I just can't seem to find the answer of why is this happening

```
def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get(
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    components = []
    data = {}
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:

        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text.replace('\n', '') # AAPL
        name = row.findAll('td')[1].text.replace('\n', '') # Apple Inc
        sector = row.findAll('td')[3].text.replace('\n', '') # Information Technology
        mapping = str.maketrans(".", "-")

        ticker = ticker.translate(mapping)
        name = name.translate(mapping)
        sector = sector.translate(mapping)

        data['ticker']=ticker
        data['name']=name
        data['sector']=sector

        print(data) # {'ticker': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc-', 'sector': 'Information Technology'}
        components.append(data) # I add each component to the list


    with open("SP500components.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(components, f)

    print(components) # this gives me the list with only the last item repeated 

    return components

save_sp500_tickers()
```

The goal is to have a list that looks like this:

```
[{'ticker': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc-', 'sector': 'Information Technology'},
{'ticker': 'ETN', 'name': 'Eaton Corporation', 'sector': 'Industrials'},
{'ticker': 'EBAY', 'name': 'eBay Inc-', 'sector': 'Consumer Discretionary'},
{'ticker': 'ECL', 'name': 'Ecolab Inc-', 'sector': 'Materials'},
{'ticker': 'EIX', 'name': "Edison Int'l", 'sector': 'Utilities'},
...,
...]
```

Instead, I get a list that only shows the last object multiple times, like this:

```
[{'ticker': 'ZTS', 'name': 'Zoetis', 'sector': 'Health Care'},
{'ticker': 'ZTS', 'name': 'Zoetis', 'sector': 'Health Care'},
{'ticker': 'ZTS', 'name': 'Zoetis', 'sector': 'Health Care'},
{'ticker': 'ZTS', 'name': 'Zoetis', 'sector': 'Health Care'},
...,
...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all down to your `data` object. You initialise it outside the for loop. Since it is a dictionary, it is mutable in python, and when you append it to the list you are simply appending a reference to that `data` dict each iteration of the loop, rather than a new dictionary. So at the end the reference just points to the most current version of the dict, hence why it appears to be the same dict multiple times - it IS the same dict.

[This page](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/#pass-by-what-exactly) may help to understand what is happening.

Try moving the initialisation of the dict inside the for loop:

```
def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get(
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    components = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text.replace('\n', '') # AAPL
        name = row.findAll('td')[1].text.replace('\n', '') # Apple Inc
        sector = row.findAll('td')[3].text.replace('\n', '') # Information Technology
        mapping = str.maketrans(".", "-")

        ticker = ticker.translate(mapping)
        name = name.translate(mapping)
        sector = sector.translate(mapping)

        data = dict(ticker=ticker, name=name, sector=sector)

        print(data) # {'ticker': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc-', 'sector': 'Information Technology'}
        components.append(data) # I add each component to the list


    with open("SP500components.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(components, f)

    print(components) # this gives me the list with only the last item repeated 

    return components
```